# How to insert a file to google drive path with apache camel java DSL

Tags: google-drive-api, apache-camel

I'm running around trying to figure out how to use Apache Camel's google-drive drive-files component to insert some files to a nested folder in the drive. So far below code is able to insert the file to the drive's root folder.

```
from("timer:bkp?period={{timer.period}}")
            .process(new BackupFile())
            .to("google-drive://drive-files/insert")
            .log("done");
```

And this is the Processor class

```
public class BackupFile implements Processor {
private static final String TEST_UPLOAD_FILE = "/path/to/file/imge.jpg";

private static final java.io.File UPLOAD_FILE = new java.io.File(TEST_UPLOAD_FILE);

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setTitle(UPLOAD_FILE.getName());
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(null, UPLOAD_FILE);
    final Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    
    headers.put("CamelGoogleDrive.content", fileMetadata);
    headers.put("CamelGoogleDrive.mediaContent", mediaContent);
    exchange.getIn().setHeaders(headers);

}
```

}

FYI I need to define the said nested path before insert i.e do some setup like

```
setPath("/mydrive/path/tofile");
```

Any help or leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It seems according to their docs, you need to include parents in the file metadata (somehow): https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create

Comment: You are right its not as easy with that google drive java api. It seems they require you to find out "ids" of those parent folders. Would like to see a simple API where even the name itself could have folder separated by slash, but that maybe does not work either? IMHO Google has not been the friendly Java API as other cloud providers do.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around I came across Node.js sample that helped. The missing information all along was that the nested folder needed to exist before we can reference it.What I was expecting was a functionality to create the folder but perhaps this can be added as improvement. The folder's ID (PARENT_ID) can also be found from the url of the folder.

Below code finally worked for me.

```
ParentReference parRef=new ParentReference();
    parRef.setId(PARENT_ID);
    List<ParentReference> parents=new ArrayList<>();
    parents.add(parRef);

    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setTitle(UPLOAD_FILE.getName());
    fileMetadata.setParents(parents);

    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(null, UPLOAD_FILE);
    final Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();

    headers.put("CamelGoogleDrive.content", fileMetadata);
    headers.put("CamelGoogleDrive.mediaContent", mediaContent);
    exchange.getIn().setHeaders(headers);
```